# Make `git svn find-rev` search the whole repository

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

When I want to get a local hash of a commit based on SVN revision id, I usually run `git svn find-rev`. However, the one big inconvenience is that this command will only look for the commit in the current branch, or in the branch explicitly specified in the command after the revision.

Sometimes, I only know the revision id, and I want to find a local hash without knowing the branch name. Is there a way to do it with `git svn find-rev`? It would make sense, knowing that SVN revisions are unique.

**EDIT:**

Turns out, there is no good way to do it.
I accepted the answer, which provides a solution, but it takes too long to search a repository with huge number of branches, like mine. I ended up writing my own shell function and using a regular `svn` in combination with `git svn`, which works much faster:

```
gitrev()
{
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "${FUNCNAME[0]} <revision> [git_args]"
    return 1
  fi
  local rev b
  rev="$1"
  shift
  b="$(svn log -v -c "$rev" "$SVN_BRANCHES_URL" | grep -m1 -Po '/branches/\K[^/]+')" &&
  git svn find-rev "r${rev#r}" "origin/$b" "$@"
}
```

If you use it, you may need to replace `grep -P` part if you're not on GNU/Linux. Revision can be specified with or without "r" prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search in all local branches you can e. g. do

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/ | xargs -l git svn find-rev r123456
```

To have it more reliable but still fast, you can do it with a little bit more complex line that looks through all refs until a match is found and then aborts, e. g. like

```
while read ref; do result="$(git svn find-rev r123456 "$ref")"; [ -n "$result" ] && echo $result && break; done < <(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)')
```

Comment: Seems like it, although in my case I have to search remote branches as well, and it takes a lot of time.

Comment: Yes, can need quite some time, especially if you have many refs and if you e. g. give all refs and the revision is in multiple branches, or in some branches and some tags, you will get the result multiple times. But it is the only short way I know. Otherwise you have to write a loop that basically does the same and stops as soon as it found a result.

Comment: Ok, I posted you another one-liner that reliably works in the whole repository and stops as soon as something was found. You can modify it a bit by adding sorting to e. g. first look into local branches, then into remote branches, then into tags or something like that.

Comment: upvoting helpful answers, including the one you are accepting :-)

Comment: well, I accepted the answer, because it answers the actual question. However, for me, this approach is still too slow, so I decided to use an entirely different method.

Comment: With the while loop it is too slow? It is quite fast here. What other approach did you use?

Comment: And btw., every helpful answer, including the accepted one should be up-voted. And especially in the accepted case it never makes sense to not up-vote, because if the answer was not helpful, it wouldn't have been accepted. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`git svn find-rev` does show the commit sha-1 value from the current branch. But you can **use shell script to search the commit from the whole repo**.

Such as if you want to get the corresponding commit from revision `r9`, then you can specify the variable `rev` value as `r9` as below:

```
#!/bin/sh

rev="r9"
for branch in $(git branch -r)
do
{
  sha=$(git svn find-rev $rev $branch)
  if [ ! -z "$sha" ]; then
  {
    echo "The revision $rev has the corresponding commit is $sha. And the commit is on $branch branch."
    break
  }
  fi
}
done
```